# jQuery Draggable - Image Map line drawing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, math, cross-browser

Like the title says, I am doing some line drawing for an image map. The problem is that the farther my mouse goes from the original coordinates, the slower the line draws. There is obviously something wrong with my math. Could someone who is good with math check this out for me and tell me whats wrong?

```
    $('map area.dp').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    cursor: 'crosshair',
    helper: function (e) {
        var h = $('<div class="drag-helper"></div>').attr('name', $(this).attr('name'));
        return h;
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {

        //orignal "constant" datapoint coords
        oX = parseInt(this.coords.split(',')[0]);
        oY = parseInt(this.coords.split(',')[1]);

        //ratio = "variable" mouse position / orginal data point
        ratX = e.pageX / oX;
        ratY = e.pageY / oY;


        //set new datapoint to draw line to by dividing mouse poistion by ratio as mouse moves across the screen
        ui.offset.left = e.pageX / ratX;
        ui.offset.top = e.pageY / ratY;

        var scrlTp = $('html')[0].scrollTop;
        var scrlLft = $('html')[0].scrollLeft;

        ui.offset.left -= scrlLft;
        ui.offset.top -= scrlTp;


        ui.position.left = ui.offset.left

        ui.helper.css('top', (ui.offset.top) + 'px');
        ui.helper.css('left', (ui.offset.left) + 'px');

        var d = $('<div id="DragLine"></div>').css('top', (ui.offset.top) + 'px').css('left', (ui.offset.left) + 'px').appendTo($('map'));
    },
    drag: function (e, ui) {


        var scrlTp = $('html')[0].scrollTop;
        var scrlLft = $('html')[0].scrollLeft;

        ui.offset.left = e.pageX / ratX
        ui.offset.top = e.pageY / ratY

        ui.offset.left -= scrlLft;
        ui.offset.top -= scrlTp;

        ui.position.left = ui.offset.left;

        if (ui.offset.left > px100) {
            ui.offset.left = px100;
            ui.position.left = px100;
        }


        var diff = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);
        if (diff < 0) {
            $('#DragLine').css('left', (ui.position.left + 4) + 'px').css('width', (diff * -1) + 'px');
        }
        else {
            $('#DragLine').css('left', (ui.originalPosition.left + 4) + 'px').css('width', diff + 'px');
        }

        ui.helper.text(pxToVal(ui.position.left));
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        $('#DragLine').remove();

        var mp = $('#MainForm #Settings_MovedPoints');
        var key = ui.helper.attr('name');
        var val = pxToVal(ui.position.left);
        strPts = mp.val();
        var pts;
        if (strPts) {
            pts = JSON.parse(strPts);
        }

        //set the new dictionary
        if (!pts) { pts = {}; }
        pts[key] = val;

        strPts = JSON.stringify(pts);
        mp.val(strPts);

        $('#MainForm').submit();
    }

})
```

Comment: What are you doing? appending `dragLine` for every registered mouse movement?

Comment: OK, now after your edit my previous comment makes no sense, right? Can you be more specific what you're actually trying to achieve? What are you dividing, what line, what for, why you use a ratio for drawing a line from point A to point B?

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry about that, this code example is more pseudo code than not. The code above is just there so you can get an idea of how I am trying to calculate the next point. The code I have actually lives in the `drag:` event of my `$('map area')'.draggable()`

Comment: I use a ratio because I am getting inconsistent values for `event.pageX' and 'event.pageY' in different browsers. Don't the comments in the code specify whats going on?

Comment: I don't think you'll get any answer based on your current question format. I cannot even imagine after a third look at your code where are you stuck at... (Probably I just miss some imagination :) ) Try to setup a demo, or explain what libraries you use, what are you trying to achieve here. Questions should, in general, provide the simplest formatted code to represent the issue... yours is just missing parts.

Comment: Okay, editted to show the actual `draggable()` method from my code.

Comment: I'm thinking that it's because I am using event.PageX in my ratio